# Using cheap Surface Pro clone as a graphics tablet input? (similar to Wacom Cintiq)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, tablet, graphics-tablet, stylus

Is it possible to use one of those cheap Surface Pro clones (such as a Chuwi Surbook, Chuwi Hi13 etc.) as a graphics tablet input on a Windows 10 PC similar to a Wacom Cintiq?

What I want to do is use the laptop/desktop to run all my processes (e.g. web browser, OneNote) and have the OneNote window displayed on the tablet, so I can use it almost as a digital notepad that is running on the laptop/desktop, but displayed on the tablet. That way I can use the tablet screen as a second monitor to the laptop/desktop, but with pen support. Is it possible to do this over USB, or if not, over Wifi?

Thanks

Comment: There are apps that can turn a touch screen into a trackpad for another computer, but the real features of graphics tablet input is in the special detection capabilities that allow differing pressure levels and angle detection, etc. There may be software that allows this, but ONLY if the tablet you're using records this sort of information and that can be accessed by the software. The software I've used for basic input function was "Unified Remote".

Comment: Have you considered using screen sharing technologies. e.g. the Windows 10 screen projection from your desktop to your tablet? https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/turn-windows-10-pc-into-wirelss-display

Comment: @someuser I don't have the tablet yet, I wanted to know about this before I purchased the tablet

Comment: You can test it out using 2 windows 10 PCs. But the part of using the touchscreen to control may not be the same as using mouse.

Comment: @someuser Yes, the touch and pen input is the aspect I specifically needed to know about

Answer (score 0):

Another user's post in [How to use a Windows tablet as a drawing tablet?](https://superuser.com/a/1247993/387361) goes like this:

> There's an app called [VirtualTablet](http://www.sunnysidesoft.com/virtualtablet/) that I believe does what you're asking. You install it on your tablet/laptop and on your desktop, and it lets you use the tablet as an input for the desktop. It won't have all of the features of a drawing tablet, and there might be some lag depending on the quality of your connection, but from my brief experience it gets the job done!

I've tried it. It lags sometimes but still useable.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try use SPACEDESK (server/client): https://spacedesk.net

As a client (wi-fi display) can be a device with Windows 10 or Android 5.0+. More convenient and faster than Miracast. You can connect up to 3 wireless displays (Android/Windows clients) and use their input capabilities (touchscreen, mouse, etc).